# Ionic android device debugging for version less or equals to 4.4.2

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Im using a real device. An Huawei mobile. Unfortunately the installed android version is 4.2.2.

I have read some resources that exaplain how to remotely debug the app in your mobile through computer's chrome tools.
All of them say you need a device with at least android 4.4.
As I said before, this phone has been shipped with 4.2.2.
Upgrading it didn't work. The phone says it is already up to date.
I have read something about ROM and rooting the phone (I know very little about that) which seems to be the solutions for forcing upgrading to newer android version. But for newbie I guess it could take some time.

So my question is if it possible to make remote debugging of ionic app having a mobile with OS <= 4.2.2

Comment: yes you can debug it.. follow these steps go to `platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml` than change the target sdk version to 19

Answer (score 3):

yes you can by  jsHybugger Plugin.

for more follow this link https://www.jshybugger.com/#!/docs